# Django - How to sort objects by an attribute of the first item in a sorted list of associated objects?

Tags: python, django, sorting, one-to-many

I want to achieve the following:

I have one object, lets assume the following classes:

```
class A():
     title

class B():
     foreign key = A.id
     time
     #one-to-many relation
```

I want to know what the view and template would look like if I wanted  to display a list like:

```
A.Title1 
B.time #A is sorted on these ones
B.time 

A.Title2
B.time #A is sorted on these ones
B.time
B.time
```

Where each set of `B()` objects associated with one `A()` object are sorted by `B.time`, and the `A()` objects themselves are sorted by the top `B.time` in these `A()` objects.

How would I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I tried Willem van Onsen's solution, but it led me to the following outcomes:
The objects I want to show:
[image: All objects]
The objects that are actually shown:
[image: Shown objects]

Comment: And would I sort the ` A()` object like:
`A.objects.select_all(B).order_by(B.objects.select_related('a').order_by('time')[0])`?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can perform perform for example an `itertools.groupby`:

```
# views.py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter
from django.db.models import Min

def some_view(request):
    bs = B.objects.prefetch_related(
        'foreign_key'
    ).annotate(
        first_b=Min('foreign_key__b__time')
    ).order_by('first_b', 'time')
    groups = groupby(bs, key=attrgetter('foreign_key'))
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'groups': groups})
```

And then as template (`some_template.html`), we can use:

```
<ul>
{% for group, items in groups %}
  <li>{{ group.title }}</li>
  <ul>
  {% for item in items %}
  <li>{{ item.time }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Almost, but I didnt want to order the A's by title, I want to order them by the top B.time's for each A

Comment: You need to order them by an attribute of `A` as well, since `groupby` works in bursts...

Comment: @NathanRuth: what you can do is sort the `A`s on the *first* related `B` object, if you want that, see update.

Comment: Really close, but now I need not only the first B object to be shown. I want to show all of them, but sort them by the lowest dates first.

Comment: @NathanRuth: this is what happens, we only *annotate* with the first `b`.